# Retrieving exit status value from executable in Ruby with Open3

Tags: ruby, testing, popen3

Launching

```
stdout, status = Open3.capture2("ls")
if (status == 0)
  puts("PASS")
else
  puts("FAIL")
```

works like a charm, however when I try to use

`stdout, status = Open3.capture2("../src/bin tests/test01.txt")`

to launch an executable `bin` with his argument's path (which works from my command line, I checked with `echo $?`), it seems to enter an infinite loop.
I tried capture3 and popen3, same thing.

Any idea about what could be wrong?

Comment: What does `../src/bin` do? Under what circumstances can it enter and infinite loop?

Comment: @simonwo It's a compiler. I guess there are many ways it could enter an infinite loop, However as said earlier, the command line works just fine and returns 0.

Comment: Can you write a script to look at the environment variables? It could be that they are key to success and only on the command line. It could also be that it’s not entering an infinite loop and is actually waiting for input from STDIN or another pipe for some reason. Or it may behave differently on purpose when invoked from a script. Have a read about psudeo-TTYs, and use the Ruby module to test this.

Comment: I also noticed that calling `$bin $file` doesn't work as well in a shell script as `"$bin $file"`, it might indeed be related in some way.